# Add whitespace after two elements of list in Text - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a dynamic list where I add element after two seconds. When I start list looks like: `[ma]`, after two seconds: `[ma, la]`, after next two seconds `[ma, la, ga]`, after next two seconds `[ma, la, ga, ba]` etc. I want to create Text which looks like: first: `ma`, after two seconds `mala`, after two seconds `mala ga`, after two seconds `mala gaba` etc.
This is my code for now:

```
Align buildItem(context, String text, double size) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32, horizontal: 100),
      child: Text(
        _visibleChar
            .toString()
            .replaceAll(" ", "")
            .replaceAll(",", '')
            .replaceAll("[", '')
            .replaceAll("]", ""),
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

but this create Text: ma, 2sec: mala, 2 sec: malaga, 2 sec: malagaba. Any hints?

Comment: please provide the function that's returning the mala gaba word after some seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you wanting, but:

```
String returnSentence(List<String> words) {
  String sentence = "";
  if (words.isNotEmpty) {
    final _lenght = words.length;
    sentence = words[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < _lenght; i++) {
      sentence += i % 2 == 0 ? (' ' + words[i]) : words[i];
    }
  }
  return sentence;
}
```

Some buttons to test:

```
TextButton(onPressed:()=> print(returnSentence(["oi","filho","meu"])), child: Text("teste1")),
TextButton(onPressed:()=> print(returnSentence(["oi"])), child: Text("teste2")),
TextButton(onPressed:()=> print(returnSentence(["oi","filho"])), child: Text("teste3")),
TextButton(onPressed:()=> print(returnSentence(["oi","filho","oi","filho","meu"])), child: Text("teste4")),
```

Testing this function on the above buttons gives you these results:

```
oifilho meu
oi
oifilho
oifilho oifilho meu
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want:

```
String joinString(List<String> strings) {
  String result = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    result += strings[i];
    if(i.isOdd) {
      result += ' ';
    }
  }
  return result;
}

void main() {
  print(joinString(['ma']));
  print(joinString(['ma', 'la']));
  print(joinString(['ma', 'la', 'ga']));
  print(joinString(['ma', 'la', 'ga', 'ba']));
}
```